# Three Uiview next to each other ,equal width, use full screen-width and after remove one the other two gets full screen-width?

Tags: ios

I have three uiview

[image]

when i remove one the other two gets full screen width.what would i do constraints ? or any suggestion to achieve this.can anyone help me please.

Comment: how you are removing UIView?

Comment: u have only these three view or more than that?

Comment: Please show your tried code.

Comment: Try to use UIStackView, if you didn't.

Comment: hii, only three views and removing programmatically.

Comment: i agree that UIStackView is one way but except this ???

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` and run the app with 3.  Use the view debugger to record _all_ the constraints.  Remove 1 view and repeat.  That will tell you what `UIStackView` did to achieve the effect, and you can use that information any way you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed these three view to a StackView.
And set UIStackView

**Axis** to **horizontal**

**Alignment** to **fill**

and **Distribution** to **FillEqually**.

To remove your view just hide that view, other views will get full screen width.